# How to loop something in my paint function?

Tags: java, mouselistener

So I am trying to set up this thing that changes an image when hovered over. I have already set up the mouseListener to know if the mouse is over my image. I have a variable that has the image location stored in it and it changes when the image is hovered over. When my paint command is run it paints the default image and when I hover over it, it doesn't change because it is not painted again. How can I make it so that it repaints it again when the image location is changed. BTW the mouseListener is in a different class than the image.

My image:

```
private String settingsConfig = snake.settingsConfig;
settingsImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(settingsConfig));
settingsImage.paintIcon(this, g, 700, 23);
```

My main class (painting method is in the other class)

```
public class snake implements MouseListener{

public static int mouseX;
public static int mouseY;

public static String settingsConfig = "/assets/settings.png";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // JFrame
    JFrame obj = new JFrame("Snake");
    gameplay Gameplay = new gameplay(); 
    obj.setBounds(10, 10, 905, 700);
    obj.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    obj.setResizable(false);
    obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    obj.add(Gameplay);
    obj.setVisible(true);

    obj.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            mouseX = e.getX();
            mouseY = e.getY();
            if(mouseX > 699 && mouseX < 761 && mouseY > 22 + 25 && mouseY < 54 + 25) {
                settingsConfig = "/assets/settingshover.png";
            }
            else {
                settingsConfig = "/assets/settings.png";
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Very small piece of paint(Graphics g) (In a different class):

```
public void paint (Graphics g) {

    if(moves == 0) {
        snakexlength[2] = 50;
        snakexlength[1] = 75;
        snakexlength[0] = 100;

        snakeylength[2] = 100;
        snakeylength[1] = 100;
        snakeylength[0] = 100;
    }

    if(moves >= 1) {
        playing = true;
    }

    // Draw title image border
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawRect(24, 10, 851, 55);

    // Draw the title image and settings
    titleImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/assets/snaketitle.jpg"));
    titleImage.paintIcon(this, g, 25, 11);

    settingsImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(settingsConfig));
    settingsImage.paintIcon(this, g, 700, 23);

    // Draw the border for gameplay
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawRect(24, 74, 851, 577);

    // Draw background for the gameplay
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(25, 75, 850, 575);

    // Draw score
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    g.drawString("Score: " + score, 780, 30);

    // Draw  high score
    g.drawString("High Score: " + highScore, 780, 50);
}
```

Comment: You already asked this question and were given duplicates plus links to many similar questions. Why are you asking it again? Why are you not showing that you gained something from the previous links? Why are you not posting a [mcve] as was requested previously?

Comment: This is different though, i'm asking about how I can loop something in my paint function

Comment: You don't loop, and you're not thinking the logic correctly. Read the duplicates. You change the state of a field in the mouse listener, and then use that change to decide what to paint. But again you're far better off swapping ImageIcons in JLabels, as was suggested previously.

Comment: The problem I am facing is how to transfer it across classes

Comment: That's the same as transferring any information across classes. Call methods. Regardless, ask a decent complete question, one with an [mcve], code that can be run, with images from online, as was suggested earlier.

Comment: @EricLeus Where is your `paintComponent(g)`? Your question is about paint function, but you didn't show us any of your paint methods...

Comment: I added a part of my paint(g) function, my question is how can I call repaint() on this in the way you showed in your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I make it so that it repaints it again when the image location is changed

Invoke `reapint();` in the place where you need the paintings to be updated. For example in the listener when you mouse-over the image.

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    mouseX = e.getX();
    mouseY = e.getY();
    if(mouseX > 699 && mouseX < 761 && mouseY > 22 + 25 && mouseY < 54 + 25){
        settingsConfig = "/assets/settingshover.png";
    }
    else{
        settingsConfig = "/assets/settings.png";
    }
    repaint();  
}
```

Comment: thanks, the problem is that my paint function is in a different class...

Comment: that's the problem I'm facing

Comment: @EricLeus Then you may want to show us your current code structure, like where is the panel and where you coded the listener..etc.

Comment: I've tried to get him to post a [mcve] before, but he hasn't listened for unknown reason